# Elliptic Curve Cryptography Point Arithmetic Libraries

Tags: elliptic-curves

Are there any libraries out there that perform ECC point arithmetic:adding,subtraction whether it be in C for micro controllers for VHDL for fpgas? Or to go further any libraries that perform ElGamal encryption/decryption?

Comment: refer this website, you may get some ideas http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~debdeep/osscrypto/psec/psecsca.html

Comment: [BearSSL](https://bearssl.org/) does offer ECC targeted at low performance embedded hardware. It doesn't offer FPGA code though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a github repository [link](https://github.com/Bren2010/ecc) with which you can implement ECC arithmetic
and a research [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.423.5411&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which gives you some idea on how to implement a software library for ECC

Hope this helps !